# NetBeans - Android ImageButton

Tags: android

I'm having a problem that can not solve. I would like your help.

I have an ImageButton that is calling another class, which is not the MainActivity. When I compile the program does not display any error but when I run the emulator and click on ImageButton he gives the following error:

"The invalid application INOV (process org.me.teste) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

Below is my MainActivity and my other class:

```
package org.me.teste;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TableLayout myTableLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TableLayout myTableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);

        ImageButton i = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.refributton);

        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagem);
        i.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        i.setAdjustViewBounds (true);

        i.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent perirefri = new Intent(org.me.teste.MainActivity.this, PerifericosRefri.class);
                    startActivity(perirefri);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Follow my class:

```
package org.me.teste;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public class PerifericosRefri extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.perifericosrefri);

        TableLayout myTableLayout2 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout2);

        ImageButton i3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.camerabutton);
        ImageButton i4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.barcodebutton);

        i3.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagem3);
        i3.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        i3.setAdjustViewBounds (true);

        i4.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagem4);
        i4.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        i4.setAdjustViewBounds (true);
    }
}
```

I am Brazilian and if I made a clerical error, I apologize.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Does logcat give any more info? My guess is that it's a nullpointerexception somewhere, but it's impossible to tell without more info.

Comment: OK. What information do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added activity `PerifericosRefri` in your android manifest file?

Comment: Yes my AndroidManifest follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="org.me.teste">
<application android:icon="@drawable/home" android:label="INOV">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="INOV">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".PerifericosRefri"/>
</application>
</manifest>